# Images showing big in size

Tags: wordpress, web, blogs

In my blog all images are showing big in size. That is actual size is something else but rendering size is too big. It is happening for gravtor and for uploaded images also. You can check this Url- https://punjiguide.com/best-share-market-books-in-hindi/
Recently i have installed Lite Speed Cache plugin. Now I have disabled it. Still problem is the same.

Please provide me wordpress solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.